# Access a SQLite db file from inside MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sqlite

Given the number of different storage engines MySQL supports, I'm just a bit surprised I can't find one that uses SQLite files.

Does such a thing exist?

---

The use case is that I have data in multiple MySQL data bases that I want to process and export as a SQLite data base that other tools can then process.

The current proposed solution is to use a scratch MySQL DB server to access the other instance using the `FEDERATED` Storage Engine and to access and populate a local SQLite db file using another Storage Engine.

The constraint is that the cost/benefit trade off can barely justify the proposed workflow (and can't justify writing any code beyond the SQL that reads and processes the federated tables) so I'm strictly limited to "works robustly out of the box" solutions.

Comment: I've never heard of a SQLite driver working inside MySQL. Would it work to have something that syncs changes from MySQL to SQLite on a delayed basis? A simple script would do that, with created/updated_at timestamps for all tables you wish to sync.

Comment: This is not my recommend or my opinion but this has no interest and this is not how it's working. To replicate/save/synchronize your db use your application and/or a cronjob. If you want to synchronize, i advise you to consider the SQLite DB as read only. Maybe you could find a lib/app/drive that can convert SQLite queries into MySQL ones.

Comment: The expected use case is a stream of one off operations (different source DBs, different processing, different output) so automation is (mostly) irrelevant.